# Commerce Shared Taxonomy

Tags: sitecore-commerce, content-search

We have a site built in Sitecore 9 with SXA. We would like to add Sitecore Commerce to this site. The current site makes use of Tags for searching. We would like to be able to tag commerce items with the same tags we use for common Sitecore items so that we can retrieve commerce items in native search results using the same filtering.

Is this possible out of the box? Or, would we need to create some kind of taxonomy service that the Sitecore commerce environment would read from and add a custom component that would allow for setting these values?

The site uses Coveo, but I think the search interface used is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

While there is no direct way of associating the tags with commerce items, you can leverage the use of tags in commerce item.You can fill in the tag field of the commerce item with the tag you want to search.For example, you want to associate tag "symposium" with commerce item, add "symposium" to tags field of commerce item and search for indexed field "tags_txm" using sitecore API to retrieve the commerce products.Here is the screenshot of how sitecore commerce tags are stored in Solr.
[image]